# Subtracting an empty dataframe returns different count than original

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes: original_df (with a number of rows) and empty_df (empty dataframe).
When I try to "subtract" empty_df from original_df and count both dataframes, the result is different:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("guid", StringType(), True)
])

empty_df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), 
                                 schema=schema)
original_df = spark.read.parquet('some_path')

diff_df = original_df.select('guid')
                     .subtract(empty_df.select('guid'))

print('Original DF count: ' + str(original_df.count()))
print('Empty DF count: ' + str(empty_df.count()))
print('Diff DF count: ' + str(diff_df.count()))

# Check difference
whats_different_df = original_df.select('guid')
                                .subtract(diff_df.select('guid'))

print('Difference between original and diff DF: ' + 
       str(whats_different_df.count()))
```

I expect as output:
Original DF count: 68724356 
Empty DF count: 0 
Diff DF count: 68724356 
Difference between original and diff DF: 0

But I had:
Original DF count: 68724356 
Empty DF count: 0 
Diff DF count: **68724294**
Difference between original and diff DF: 0

Note: I have tried with a small example (dummy data, not the original one) and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the answer: I needed to drop duplicates when loading original_df:

```
original_df = spark.read.parquet('some_path').drop_duplicates(['guid'])
```

because subtract function is equivalent to 'EXCEPT DISTINCT' in SQL